# Jade: How to write closing tag with text element after it

Tags: html, pug

How do I write this HTML in Jade? Especially I have problems with the `i`-element and the text after that.

```
<div class="fileDrop">
    <p class="bold"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</p>
</div>
```

This one is wrong

```
div.fileDrop
    p.bold
        i.fa.fa-upload Upload
```

... as it gives me

```
<div class="fileDrop">
    <p class="bold"><i class="fa fa-upload">Upload</i></p>
</div>
```

So the Text should be after the `i`-element with space between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation describes how to include plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/):

```
div.fileDrop
  p.bold
    i.fa.fa-upload
    |  Upload
```

Comment: It may be beneficial to explicitly point out the double space after the bar in last line.